# How to change size of font in angular material form fields of floating place holder

Tags: css, angular, forms, sass, angular-material2

Below is the form field of angular material.
How can I add 2 different customize font-size for placeholder when it's normal and when it floats.
font-size : 20px; (When it is normal)
font-size : 13px; (When it floats up and get smaller)

```
 <mat-form-field class="form-group example-full-width">
    <input matInput id="Fname" placeholder="First" class=" " formControlName="FirstName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="firstName.invalid" class="">First name is required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The floating text is a label that can be targeted with css. Something like this may work.

```
mat-form-field label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And when the label is floated

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-should-float label {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Flignats, I was running all over the place.

Comment: Does this work on recent versions of Angular? Using Angular and Angular Material 10. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See my answer below for an up to date version.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer no longer works, here is how I did it :

```css
.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label,
.mat-form-field-can-float .mat-input-server:focus + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label {
  transform: translateY(-1.34375em) scale(1) !important; /* originally scale(0.75) */
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go, but you'll also need to add: margin-top: 0 !important;

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me, you could try this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. example@example.com">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.mat-form-field{
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 280px;
    &.mat-focused{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .mat-input-element{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    &::placeholder{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
 }

.mat-form-field-should-float {    
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Official Angular Material documentation for Form Field](https://v14.material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#theming) **(since v5)** has a recommendation  for changing the font size as it follows:

> mat-form-field inherits its font-size from its parent element. This can be overridden to an explicit size using CSS. We recommend a specificity of at least 1 element + 1 class.

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The same way may be changed label in form field:

```
  mat-label.mat-label {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Nevertheless, if you want to keep your styles more readable, you can use **simple  css class** to apply new font properties:

```
.html

`<mat-form-field class="new-form-theming">..`.

.css

.new-form-theming {
   font-size: 24px;
   line-height: 28px;
   font-weight: 500;
 }
```