# Switching off the floating label for Material Select in Angular 15?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600605/material-design-how-to-disconnect-float-label-for-select) indicates that it is possible to turn off the float for Angular Material and I tried it this solution:

```
.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label,
  .mat-form-field-can-float .mat-input-server:focus + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label{
    display: none !important;
  }
```

However no love.  [Here's the stackblitz attempt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6mxsu-5adblv?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.scss).  The SCSS is placed in `styles.scss`.

Anyone know if it's possible to turn off the float for select fields in Angular 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new API, it seems that to remove the floating placeholder, it should be

```
.mdc-notched-outline[ng-reflect-open='true'] .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wandrille - I tried that and it also nukes the Placeholder ... Do you know how to switch off the float but keep the placeholder?

Comment: I have updated the code, I have tried it. It should be good

Comment: Wow!!  That totally works!!  Thank you so much!!  You ROCK!!